# Permission denied when trying to read a csv file using pandas in Google cloud platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to read a csv file in GCP. I got the zip file directly in my GCP instance and extracted it to get this csv file. When I try to read it, I get the following error message:

```
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a41ca2a2c686> in <module>
----> 1 df = pd.read_csv('trainset.csv',engine='python',encoding = "utf-8")
      2 df.head()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1145                     ' "python-fwf")'.format(engine=engine)
   1146                 )
-> 1147             self._engine = klass(self.f, **self.options)
   1148 
   1149     def _failover_to_python(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, **kwds)
   2291             encoding=self.encoding,
   2292             compression=self.compression,
-> 2293             memory_map=self.memory_map,
   2294         )
   2295         self.handles.extend(handles)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in _get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text)
    397         if encoding:
    398             # Encoding
--> 399             f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
    400         elif is_text:
    401             # No explicit encoding

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'trainset.csv'
```

My code that I'm using to read the file is like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('trainset.csv',engine='python')
df.head()
```

I've already seen the other similar queries online but most of them can't be applied to GCP.

Comment: You can open the file yourself just fine?

Comment: I didn't download the file due to memory constraints in my system. I got it directly in my GCP instance using curlWget.

Comment: I’m not familiar with CGP, but is there any way you can access a terminal to check if you have access to the file from there?

Comment: What do you mean by a GCP instance?  GCP is Google Cloud Platform ... which is a suite of products to build and run applications in the Cloud.  Where are you running your Python?  Possible answers could be "In Cloud Shell", "In a Compute Engine", "In a Cloud Function", "In GKE", "In Cloud Run"

Comment: @Kolban Good point, that’s important information.

Comment: @Kolban I'm running it in my compute engine

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, yes, I can access a terminal. Do you have any Ideas?

Comment: @MayankKhanna Check the current working directory, and check where the file is.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lied in the GCP compute engine instance being given way too little RAM to work with but the file was very big.

Changing the size of the RAM worked with the below command in the terminal(click on SSH and type the following below):

```
chmod 777 trainset.csv
```

Then start your jupyter notebook normally.

Credits: GCP customer support.